# How do I get small delta files (files changes) using diff?

Tags: git, svn, diff

I would like to produce delta files, ie. files containing changes between 2 files, that are small in size.

However, when I run the diff utility with the -u format to create a unified format diff file, the file size is too large.

I have 2 text files with its contents as seen below

1.txt: "hello1234"

2.txt: "hello5678"

when running "diff -u 1.txt 2.txt" the resulting diff file is 182 bytes as seen below:

--- 1.txt   2014-05-12 03:54:58.000000000 -0400

+++ 2.txt   2014-05-12 03:55:03.000000000 -0400

@@ -1 +1 @@

-hello1234

\ No newline at end of file

+hello5678

\ No newline at end of file

this is huge compared to the original files which are only 9 bytes in size.

is there a utility or some other method that produces diff files that are smaller than the source files (e.g. svn/git utilities)?

the intent is to transfer these delta files over the network in the event of a file update instead of transferring the whole file itself.

Comment: Without that data, `patch` can't operate properly. You asked for a specific diff format, that is the format. Can you point the remote end at your VCS and use its built-in methods for pulling updates? What about compressing your files for transmission, either by zipping or using a method that has built-in compression like SFTP or scp?

Comment: @nope Challenge question - you've presented two files containing 9 bytes each, which differ in 4 of them. Can you propose a "diff" format that unambiguously identifies which 4 bytes in the original file need to be changed and to what they need to be changed in less than 9 bytes? What if the change was from "h1e2l3l4o" to "h5e6l7l8o"?

Answer (score 0):

If you want *small* "delta" files, don't use diff/patch they are not really meant for this use (in particular the `diff -u`, the normal mode is somewhat more concise).
You should use xdelta, bsdiff or something similar instead (i.e. binary oriented). A character oriented text diff might do better as well than simple `diff`.

There are cases when there is no way to express the changes more efficiently than repeating the whole file however (some files contain a high density of changes with unpredictable places). Your case is such a case, the good news is that typical cases are really better than that, even on databases or complex source codes.

There are notable cases where delta don't work: encrypted or compressed files. In this cases, the file delta should be computed on decrypted/decompressed versions.